# Dynamically change the browsers (Mostly between IE and Chrome) when navigating the URL in flex/HTML/JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, apache-flex

It might be some stupid question but I am in a strange situation where I need switching of browsers (between IE and chrome) depending on the condition.

If I click on some buttonX - it should navigate to Chrome browser.

If I click on some buttonY - it should navigate to IE browser.

This functionality I need to implement on Apache Flex, please share if any Idea to make this possible in JSP/HTML.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a stupid question, i'd love this feature...

you can start Chrome from IE using ActiveX Controls, but I think, it's not possible to start IE from Chrome

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: 1st part is comment, 2nd is answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I've actually put an answer up for all of the questions I've searched on!  Hope it works for you.

Using ActiveX, you can accomplish this from IE to Chrome, I'm not sure how to do it from Chrome to IE.

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var url = 'http://google.com';
function OpenChrome()
{

  oShell.Run('chrome.exe ' + url, 1);
}
function OpenIE()
{

  oShell.Run('iexplore.exe ' + url, 1);
}
```